# Cannot display value inside array adapter

Tags: android

```
 public class DeviceListActivity extends Activity {
        protected static final String TAG = "TAG";
        private BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;
        private ArrayAdapter<String> mPairedDevicesArrayAdapter;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle mSavedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(mSavedInstanceState);
            requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_device_list);

            setResult(Activity.RESULT_CANCELED);
            mPairedDevicesArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                    R.layout.activity_device_list, RESULT_CANCELED);

            ListView mPairedListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.paired_devices);
            mPairedListView.setAdapter(mPairedDevicesArrayAdapter);
            mPairedListView.setOnItemClickListener(mDeviceClickListener);

            mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
            Set<BluetoothDevice> mPairedDevices = mBluetoothAdapter
                    .getBondedDevices();

            if (mPairedDevices.size() > 0) {
                // findViewById(R.id.title_paired_devices).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                for (BluetoothDevice mDevice : mPairedDevices) {
                    mPairedDevicesArrayAdapter.add(mDevice.getName() + "\n"
                            + mDevice.getAddress());
                }
            } else {
                String mNoDevices = "None Paired";// getResources().getText(R.string.none_paired).toString();
                mPairedDevicesArrayAdapter.add(mNoDevices);
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onDestroy() {
            super.onDestroy();
            if (mBluetoothAdapter != null) {
                mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
            }
        }

        private OnItemClickListener mDeviceClickListener = new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> mAdapterView, View mView,
                    int mPosition, long mLong) {
                mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
                String mDeviceInfo = String.valueOf(mPairedDevicesArrayAdapter
                        .getItem(mPosition).toString());
                String mDeviceAddress = mDeviceInfo
                        .substring(mDeviceInfo.length() - 17);
                Log.v(TAG, "Device_Address " + mDeviceAddress);

                Bundle mBundle = new Bundle();
                mBundle.putString("DeviceAddress", mDeviceAddress);
                Intent mBackIntent = new Intent();
                mBackIntent.putExtras(mBundle);
                setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, mBackIntent);
                finish();
            }
        };

    }
```

**device_list.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title_paired_devices"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#666"
            android:paddingLeft="5dip"
            android:text="My Text"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/paired_devices"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:stackFromBottom="true" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

I write Above code to display all the Bluetooth device inside a ListView that are currently online.But when I try this code  i  get following exception.This Code Is working fine without using Array adapter

```
 11-04 12:03:48.504: E/AndroidRuntime(8902): java.lang.IllegalStateException: ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID to be a TextView
```

Comment: also when you add new data to adapter call `notifyDataSetChanged` on your adapter to refresh lsitvew

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error states `ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID to be a TextView`.

[The docs on ArrayAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#ArrayAdapter%28android.content.Context,%20int%29)

> public ArrayAdapter (Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId)
>
> Constructor
>
> Parameters
>   context The current context.
>
> resource
>   The resource ID for a layout file containing a layout to use when instantiating views.
>
> textViewResourceId
>   **The id of the *TextView* within the layout resource to be populated**

`RESULT_CANCELED` doesn't appear to be the ID of a TextView in your layout.  You're also passing it the same layout that you set the activity's content view to, which is also likely incorrect.

I recommend reading [Building Layouts with an Adapter](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html#AdapterViews) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Change this

```
mPairedDevicesArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                R.layout.activity_device_list, RESULT_CANCELED);
```

to

```
mPairedDevicesArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, RESULT_CANCELED);
```

The above uses a built in layout  `android.R.layout.simple_list_tiem1` for the listview

```
11-04 12:03:48.504: E/AndroidRuntime(8902): java.lang.IllegalStateException: ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID to be a TextView
```

You have wrong params for your adapter.

or

```
mPairedDevicesArrayAdapte = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, RESULT_CANCELED);
```

`list_item.xml` // only textview in the xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="test"
    />
```

Or

```
    mPairedDevicesArrayAdapte= new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item,R.id.textView1, RESULT_CANCELED);
```

Have `list_item.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:padding="5dip" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="test"
    />

</RelativeLayout>
```